# Calculating average excluding zeros ignoring slicer for a measure in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am creating the following measure that calculates average scores of all the students excluding scores that are zero.

```
measure= calculate(average(table[score]),filter(table, table[score]<>0))
```

However,I want to compare this measure against a selected student score using the slicer.

```
new measure= calculate(average(table[score]),all(table[student]),filter(table, table[score]<>0))
```

However, the new measure is the same score as the student and it is not ignoring the slicer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AVERAGEX` and `IF` to calculate the average excluding some records based on some condition.

```
Average Excluding Zero =
AVERAGEX (
    Table,
    IF ( Table[Score] <> 0, Table[Score] )
)
```

Then,

```
All Students Average Excluding Zero =
CALCULATE (
    [Average Excluding Zero],
    ALL ( Table[Student] )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In generall, there is no way to make a measure ignore a particular slicer.

There are a few other options:

1. You can use the `ALL()` function. This way the measure ignores all filters
2. You can edit filter interactions. For example the measure is in a KPI card. You can cancel the interaction between your slicer and the KPI card then. This way you can ignore single filters, but it gets applied on the visual interaction and not on the calculation itself.
3. You can calculate two different measures for your purpose, like @Kosuke recommended